# Why can I not reference my jQuery object inside a callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, click, bind

I store a jquery object (a collection of html elements) but when I come to reference the object in another function it comes back as 'undefined'! Here's my code:

```
this.container = $('#slide-menu'), // The menu container (e.g. a UL)
this.items = this.container.find('.menu-item'); // The menu items (e.g. all li's)
this.links = this.items.find('.link'); // The menu links

this.getCurrent(); // Set the current menu-item
this.getPrev(); // Set the previous menu-item
this.getNext(); // Set the next menu-item

console.log(this.items); // !!! The items exist here !!!

// Setup the menu items click events:
this.items.bind('click', function(e) {

    console.log(this.items); // !!! But not here !!! ???

    e.preventDefault();
    o = $(e.currentTarget); // Set jquery object

    if (!o.hasClass('active')) { // Prevent action on current menu-item
        this.items.find('.active').removeClass('active'); // Remove the current active menu-item
        o.addClass('active'); // Set new active menu item
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening because it's driving me crazy and as far as I can see this should not be possible. Is javascript is broken?! Hmmm, what do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When is an jquery object not an object?

Never.

> When it's undefined!

Or when it's not where you think it is.

> Does anyone have any idea why this is happening because it's driving
>   me crazy and as far as I can see this should not be possible. Is
>   javascript is broken?! Hmmm, what do you think?

No, Javascript is not "broken".

You've assumed `this.items` always refers to the same thing. It does not. Inside your `bind`, `this` is the thing that was clicked on, rather than whatever it is outside of that callback function.

Inside your callback, you ought to write `$('#slide-menu').find('menu-item')` rather than `this.items`.

Comment: Doh! Yeah you're absolutely right, rookie mistake sorry. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

It's a scope problem.

`this` outside of your click event handler is not the same as `this` inside the handler. Inside the handler it refers to the element being clicked. Outside it is likely the global window object.

This should work fine:

```
var items = this.container.find('.menu-item');

items.bind('click', function(e) {
     console.log(items);
```

Don't use `this` in JavaScript unless you actually need to.

Comment: I don't like the look of that circular dependency.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal circular dependency?

Comment: A function referenced in the DOM is bound to a variable in Javascript. And your Javascript has a reference to the function. I think? I'd not reference `items` from inside the function, but re-obtain it within the callback.

Comment: It depends whether the list of elements in `items` is likely to change. If not then surely it's a good idea to cache the result rather than process the selector every time the click event fires?

Comment: Thanks yeah, I swapped the 'this' causing problems with the global reference to the parent object and it works fine now. Good advice about using 'this': I think setting specific variables to store and refer to required objects is less prone to error or confusion!

Comment: @RichardD: I'd always rather avoid memory leaks in the first instance, and perform "optimisations" later.